# Correct way to deal with an InterruptedException when implemeting an interface which does not throw it

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

The scenario is as follows.

I implement an interface reading like this:

```
public interface MessageSourceProvider
{
    MessageSource getMessageSource(Locale locale);
}
```

There are two implementations of this interface: one which reads from static sources, which are fully initialized at "constructor time", and one which does not; this latter implementation goes like this (`expiryEnabled` is an `AtomicBoolean`; comments removed, full source [here](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/msgsimple/provider/LoadingMessageSourceProvider.java); `sources` is a `Map<Locale, FutureTask<MessageSource>>`):

```
@Override
public MessageSource getMessageSource(final Locale locale)
{
    if (!expiryEnabled.getAndSet(true))
        setupExpiry(expiryDuration, expiryUnit);

    FutureTask<MessageSource> task;

    synchronized (sources) {
        task = sources.get(locale);
        if (task == null || task.isCancelled()) {
            task = loadingTask(locale);
            sources.put(locale, task);
            service.execute(task);
        }
    }

    try {
        final MessageSource source = task.get(timeoutDuration, timeoutUnit);
        return source == null ? defaultSource : source;
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // <-- HERE
        return defaultSource;
    } catch (ExecutionException ignored) {
        return defaultSource;
    } catch (TimeoutException ignored) {
        task.cancel(true);
        return defaultSource;
    } catch (CancellationException ignored) {
        return defaultSource;
    }
}
```

As the interface itself does not declare to throw `InterruptedException` (since some implementations will never do so), I do `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()`. I do this for the sake of conforming to the interface. In turn, implementations of this interface are used as such in the "main", user facing class:

```
public String getMessage(final Locale locale, final String key)
{
    BUNDLE.checkNotNull(key, "query.nullKey");
    BUNDLE.checkNotNull(locale, "query.nullLocale");

    String ret;
    MessageSource source;

    for (final Locale l: LocaleUtils.getApplicable(locale))
        for (final MessageSourceProvider provider: providers) {
            source = provider.getMessageSource(l);
            if (source == null)
                continue;
            ret = source.getKey(key);
            if (ret != null)
                return ret;
        }

    // No source found which has the key... Return the key itself.
    return key;
}
```

Now, the problem is with the `FutureTask`. As `.get()` is blocking, an `InterruptedException` can be thrown. And since the base interface does not declare to throw the exception, if I catch one I choose to restore the thread interruption status.

Literature, however, disagrees: it says that you should only do that, or ignore the exception, only in the event that you are within a `Thread` that you created yourself.

My question is: this being a user facing API, is there a potential problem with the way I am currently dealing with this? If yes, how do I fix that?

Comment: whatever literature you are referring to is _wrong_.  your handling is correct.

Comment: @jtahlborn this is JCIP. But maybe my _interpretation_ of what JCIP is saying is wrong. In fact, it is very likely.

Comment: where does it say you should not perpetuate the interrupted status? (don't have the book on hand).

Comment: I have the book at hand and it says that the only possibility where you can possibly ignore the interrupt is inside a thread you created on your own; the next recommendation is to throw it back, and only then to restore the interruption status

Comment: k, so as far as i can tell, you are following the instructions exactly.  you can't throw it, so next best thing is to restore the status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, the problem is with the FutureTask. As .get() is blocking, an InterruptedException can be thrown. And since the base interface does not declare to throw the exception, if I catch one I choose to restore the thread interruption status.

This is exactly correct.  You should *always* do it that way.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // InterruptedException clears interrupt flag
    // I always re-interrupt the thread first
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    // then i decide if I want the thread to return or throw or ...
    return;
}
```

I would say also that you should think about what it means for your thread to be interrupted.  Someone interrupted the thread that is calling `future.get()`.  How should that thread respond?

- Should it throw a `RuntimeException`?
- Should it stop doing what it is doing and quit?
- Should it shutdown the thread-pool?

> Literature, however, disagrees: it says that you should only do that, or ignore the exception, only in the event that you are within a Thread that you created yourself.

I'm not sure what literature you are looking at but IMO it is incorrect or is being imprecise.

Comment: The literature I am refering to is actually JCIP. Maybe I am taking what it says a little too seriously here...

Comment: As I recall, JCIP says that throwing is the *easiest*, not best, way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring the interrupt flag is perfectly legitimate, as discussed in **Java Concurrency in Practice**, for example.

Comment: Yup, it is JCIP, and comments from codereview.stackexchange.com, which prompted me to do it this way... This same book however says that the best way is to throw it back, which I cannot afford here :/